# Character code representation of decimal digit

Tags: ascii, character-codes

> Differentiate between the character code representation of a decimal digit and its pure binary representation

I study computer science and this is a concept I need to know for the exams but I am not sure I fully understand it

### Character code representation of 261 (for example)

Would this just be the ASCII code equivalent?

Meaning:

**2** has ASCII code **50**

**6** has ASCII code **54**

**1** has ASCII code **49**

So the character code representation is 50, 54, 49

### **Pure Binary code representation**

Is this just the binary conversion of 261?

So 100000101?

Comment: You should notice that the character encoding was not specified in the problem statement, including the number of bits. An answer could state that ASCII, which has 8-bit code units is assumed as an example. Regarding 261, reasonable people would put that in double quotes to indicate that it is meant as a sequence of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASCII defines character digits 0 to 9 with the decimal number codes 48 to 57.

So there is a representation in binary for the character but also for the the decimal digit.

The binary representation of *the character* 46 is: `00110100 00110110`. 
The character 4 is code 52 in ASCII; hence, you get `00110100`. While character 6 is 54, for which you get `00110110`.

Meanwhile, the *decimal number* 46 is stored in a 16-bit word with the following representation: `00000000 00101110`.

For the character 261, you would need to get the ASCII code for 2, 6 and 1.

2: 50

6: 54

1: 49

So you get for 50, 54, 49 : `00110010 00110110 00110001`

Comment: Thanks for explaining :)